# Clojure - Currying technicalities

Tags: clojure, currying

I'm aware that clojure does not have built-in support for currying . But I would like to understand the technicalities of why this code fails -->

```
(defn area-of-triangle
  "Takes the lengths a b and the angle c"
  [a b c]
  (Math/abs (* 0.5 a b (Math/sin c))))


(defn curry
  [a]
  (fn [b]
    (fn [c] ((area-of-triangle a b c)))))
```

Running this in the repl -->

```
(def a (curry 3))
(def b (a 4))
(def c (b 54.7))

ClassCastException java.lang.Double cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  user$curry$fn__1737$fn__1738.invoke (:4)
```

Could someone explain what is happening here? Why doesn't c become the value computed by the area-of-triangle function?

Much appreciated, Alex

Comment: Just to clear up any confusion, the code in this question works fine, there’s simply an excess pair of brackets on the last line. The error has nothing to do with currying or `partial`, you get the same eg in `((inc 1.0))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are here:

1. You have got extra brackets around **(area-of-triangle a b c)**
2. For currying you can use **[partial](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partial)** function

e.g.:

```
(defn area-of-triangle
  "Takes the lengths a b and the angle c"
  [a b c]
  (Math/abs (* 0.5 a b (Math/sin c))))


(def a (partial area-of-triangle 3))
(def b (partial a 4))
(def c (b 54.7))  ;; 5.7698490053091875
```

Comment: So it is not actually possible without the partial function? I just thought it was the most idiomatic way not the only way

Comment: No, it's not possible to do it without partial.

Comment: @Alex Well, it *actually is* possible without `partial` since `partial` isn't "magic"; it's just [defined using standard language constructs](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2606). It's just that there's no point in reinventing the wheel since it does its intended purpose well (besides being overly verbose).

Comment: You're right. I said that's not possible to do it "without" partial function not to reinventing wheel.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the double function call here:

```
((area-of-triangle a b c))
```

You are calling the result of the function `area-of-triangle` as a function.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra set of parenthesis:

```
(fn [c] ((area-of-triangle a b c)))
        ^
```

This is a problem because `area-of-triangle` evaluates to a number. Say it evaluated to 10, then you have:

```
(fn [c] (10))
```

Which doesn't make any sense, since 10 isn't callable.